# How do I distribute this polynomial expansion?

Tags: polynomials

Ok, so for some reason, I cannot seem to get this simple polynomial multiplication correct no matter how many times I do it. I am working in $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$.

$$
(4x+11)(5x+(3x^2+1)) $$

Don't I just distribute the $(4x+11)$ term into the parentheses? I get $$(7x^2+3x)+(12x^3+7x^2+4x+11)$$ after distributing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can regroup two sets of two terms to simplify things further.

Comment: I realize that but according to Mathematica, I wouldn't get the correct answer.

Comment: What does Mathematica give? Odds are what you get and what it says are equivalent modulo some... *modular* arithmetic.

Comment: Ok, they are equivalent. This is a smaller part of a bigger problem, so I must be doing something else wrong then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  Just distribute everything as you normally would, then mod out all the coefficients by $13$ when you are finished.

After just distributing, you should get $12x^3 + 53x^2 + 59x + 11$.

Then, you should get $12x^3 + x^2 + 7x + 11$ after modding out.

Of course, there are some tricks to make the distribution a lot easier.  For example, recognize that $11 \equiv -2 \pmod{13}$.